# gnu fileutils upgrade for rtems install

Tags: upgrade, gnu, fileutils, rtems

To install RTEMS and all the requirements, I need the install bin to work correctly and it seems not to be the case.

Indeed, when I try "install -c -d tmp/foo/bar" it doesn't create the directories as it should.

On the RTEMS doc, they say I need to upgrade GNU fileutils, but how should I do so? I've search the internet but found nothing...

You can see the concerned RTEMS getting started page [here](http://rtems.org/onlinedocs/doc-current/share/rtems/html/started/started_15.html#Distribution-Independent-Potential-GNU_002fLinux-Issues).

I'm running a centos 6.3 virtual machine.

Thanks,
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

For the original issue, you need to install an updated [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). Nowadays, you should use the [RTEMS Source Builder (RSB)](http://www.rtems.org/wiki/index.php/RSB) to get started with RTEMS, because RSB will build all the dependencies you need in a host-independent fashion.